# MediaWiki - four garbage characters before HTML content for 404

Tags: mediawiki

So I've just installed MediaWiki for the first time and am having a weird problem which I can't find a solution to. I have been crawling the help docs, searching Google and reading articles for the last couple of hours and can't find an answer.

Everything is working fine, except on a 404 page, four garbage characters are output before the HTML. All other pages appear to be fine, just the 404s. They are different on each one and look to me to be in hex, I've seen numbers and no letter higher than an f.

**Examples**

- http://wiki.oneltd.co.uk/wiki/Onekipedia:Community_portal
- http://wiki.oneltd.co.uk/wiki/Onekipedia:General_disclaimer
- http://wiki.oneltd.co.uk/wiki/Onekipedia:Privacy_policy

I have reinstalled it twice with the same problem each time.

**System setup**

- Centos 5.6
- Apache 2.2.3 running with an nginx (0.8.55) reverse proxy
- PHP 5.3.2
- MySQL 5.0.77

**Server configs**

Apache

```
<VirtualHost 127.0.0.1:8080>
    DocumentRoot /home/sites/oneltd.co.uk/wiki
    ServerName wiki.oneltd.co.uk
    Alias /wiki /home/sites/oneltd.co.uk/wiki/index.php
    <Directory "/home/sites/oneltd.co.uk/wiki">
            Allowoverride all
    </Directory>
    CustomLog /home/sites/oneltd.co.uk/_logs/access_log "combined"
    ErrorLog /home/sites/oneltd.co.uk/_logs/error_log
</VirtualHost>
```

nginx

```
server {
    listen 205.186.146.37:80;
    server_name wiki.oneltd.co.uk;
    server_name_in_redirect off;

    access_log /home/sites/oneltd.co.uk/_logs/nginx.access_log;

    location / {
            proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:8080;
            proxy_set_header Host $host;
            proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
            proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
    }


    location ~ \.(jpg|jpeg|png|gif|swf|flv|mp4|mov|avi|wmv|m4v|mkv|ico|js|css|txt|html|htm)$ {
            root /home/sites/oneltd.co.uk/wiki;
            gzip on;
            gzip_comp_level 2;
            gzip_vary on;
            gzip_proxied any;
            gzip_types text/plain text/xml text/css application/x-javascript;
            expires max;
    }
}
```

Any help or ideas of where to look will be greatly appreciated :)

**EDIT - PROBLEM FIXED!**

Thanks to Greg Hewgill's response about the chunked encoding, I managed to find the problem. It turns out that nginx can't talk HTTP/1.1 when working as a reverse proxy, but you can force Apache to downgrade to 1.0. I found the answer after reading about [a similar problem with Drupal](http://drupal.org/node/355170)

Updated Apache config:

```
<VirtualHost 127.0.0.1:8080>
    DocumentRoot /home/sites/oneltd.co.uk/wiki
    ServerName wiki.oneltd.co.uk
    Alias /wiki /home/sites/oneltd.co.uk/wiki/index.php
    <Directory "/home/sites/oneltd.co.uk/wiki">
            Allowoverride all
    </Directory>
    CustomLog /home/sites/oneltd.co.uk/_logs/access_log "combined"
    ErrorLog /home/sites/oneltd.co.uk/_logs/error_log


    # nginx can't deal with HTTP/1.1 at the moment, force downgrade to 1.0
    SetEnv force-response-1.0 1
    SetEnv downgrade-1.0 1
</VirtualHost>
```

Comment: There is also an extra `0` at the end of the page.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This sounds like it might be somehow related to [HTTP chunked transfer encoding](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chunked_transfer_encoding). With chunked transfer, the length of each chunk is sent in hex before the actual content.

I don't know why this would be a problem in your install, or how to fix it, but it might be useful information when searching for a solution.

Comment: That seems to be the cause - the 404 pages have a `Transfer-Encoding: chunked, chunked` header, while the normal pages do not.

Comment: Brilliant - thanks for the pointer, I've found a solution. It turns out that nginx can't talk HTTP 1.1, but you can force apache to downgrade to 1.0 which solves the problem using: "SetEnv force-response-1.0 1" and "SetEnv downgrade-1.0 1"

Comment: I've marked this as the accepted solution as it pointed me in the right direction and had it fixed in 10 minutes, I've updated the question to include my solution